# Is System Call a Process?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

As per my understanding system call is set of kernel code and it's executed by exception or interrupt. I need to know whether system call is a process or not?

Comment: It's not a process as in it's not a running process with a PID. If you mean other sense of process, feel free to specify.

Comment: What do you mean by "process"?

Answer (score 3):

A process can make a system call. Originally on a x86 machine this involved loading the registers to indicate which call was required and then executing an 'int 0x80' instruction. This software interrupt instruction caused the x86 processor to switch to the kernel, where it looked at the value in the registers and then proceeded to do the open or read or write or close or seek or whatever the desired system call was.

Asking if a system call is a process or not is like asking "is a bird a travel plan or not"? The answer is **not**. You might plan your travel to see a bird. A process, in order to do anything useful, will make system calls (in theory another process could monitor shared memory or use ptrace so a process didn't need to make system calls, there is never a 100% answer) but they are not remotely the same kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

A process is a running instance of some code. Take an example binary /bin/bash. The code exists on disk. Each time you execute /bin/bash a new process is created.

At a given instant each CPU is either executing in User or Kernel mode. User mode indicates user space code execution, Kernel mode is kernel code execution.

A systemcall is a means for some user code to enter kernel mode. Systemcalls are made in a process context. When a systemcall is executed the same process enters kernel mode. No new process is created to run that systemcall.